# INNER JOIN paginated

Tags: mysql, pagination

I'm working on a simple program that displays the result of an `inner join` query in a paginated manner.

```
$get_all_query_he_for_sale = "SELECT * FROM ads INNER JOIN ads_details ON ads.ads_id = ads_details.ads_id WHERE category_id = '1'";
$get_all_query_he_for_sale_execute = mysql_query($get_all_query_he_for_sale);

<div class = "container">
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_all_query_he_for_sale_execute)){ ?>
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-md-6">
            <?php echo $row['company_name']; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

I need some help to construct it properly.

The output should be: result will display 10 records per page.

Comment: is there a question here?

Comment: @Pete yes sir, I'm trying to make a paginated result in a inner join query.

Comment: Try adding LIMIT at the end of the query?

Comment: Your question still isn't clear. Are you asking how to use the `LIMIT` clause to select certain rows of the results?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364349/pagination-using-mysql-limit-offset

Comment: @cakan what I want is a paginated... where I can show atleast 10 records per page.

Comment: In that case you must add LIMIT 0,30 for example at the end of your page and increase offset value (0) for each page.