# How to fetch first 10 rows and then next time fetch other 10 rows from mysql database table

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating API in php for android project. where I need to Create Product items API that gives first 10 records when request method pass 0
value, and gives 10 records more when value is 1.
Thus API gives 0-10,11-20 records each time request is made with some int value.
currently I am doing this:

```
$prod=$_REQUEST['prod']; 
$result= sql("SELECT * FROM products where pID='$prod'"); 
echo json_encode(array('item'=>$result));
```

But it gives me all products from table. how can I get 0-10, then 11-20 and so on.

Comment: `... ORDER BY <some_field> LIMIT <offset>, <limit>...`

Comment: Pagination. Google it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `pID` > $prod ORDER BY `pID` ASC LIMIT 10"
```

This query fetches all products with `pID` higher than `$prod`, orders them by `pID` ascending, and limits the result to 10 rows. So the `$prod` you send will the `pID` of the last record you fetched.

I suggest you look some more into mySQL since this is fairly basic stuff. [Here's a basic tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/basic-mysql-tutorial.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use  pagination then you learn about limit and offset what are limit and offset and how works in pagination.

```
 $limit=10;        ////per  page
 $start=$_REQUEST['your-requested-offset'];0,1,2,3, and so on 

$query="SELECT * FROM TABLE $limit, $start";
```

more you read this Artical about Limit and Offset
[Pagination using MySQL LIMIT, OFFSET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364349/pagination-using-mysql-limit-offset)

for how work pagination? read this artical

[Paginate Data With PHP](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928)