# How do I use LIMIT and OFFSET properly in PDO MySql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I asked a question yesterday titled "How do i use binded variables with MySql LIMIT clause.  Sorry, I guess it was not clear enough and got 30 views but no suggestions.  So here is what I found after a day of trial and error.  First, I discovered that the the LIMIT is the actual physical position of a record in a table not my auto_incremented id_ number.  A lot of documentation i read also indicated it was the OFFSET that held the record position, so I wasted a lot of time with weird results.  Second, I found documentation with a couple of ways to bind a variable to LIMIT.  None of them worked, so I resorted to assigning a $variable to the LIMIT as follows.

```
("SELECT * FROM $livetable WHERE cust_zip = :cust_zip
HAVING distance < :mydistance ORDER BY client_id ASC LIMIT $start_record_position 
, $how_many_records_to_display");
```

This works for me but any better suggestions, would be appreciated.  And I hope this will save someone else a day of figuring this out.

Comment: Are you asking how LIMIT and OFFSET work with MySQL or is there a specific problem you're having with using them through PDO? Limit is the number of items, offset is where to start.

Comment: Thats what all the docs say that I have read to.  But I is working backwards for me, where LIMIT $_where_to_start, $_number_of_items.  And if I use the word OFFSET in my code I get a error, so I have to use the format of LIMIT a , b

Comment: The above was only my first step, still needs page control for next and previous.  I think this stack overflow article will answer all my questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364349/pagination-using-mysql-limit-offset

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364349/pagination-using-mysql-limit-offset