# How is it possible to create a 100% height of the body, scrollable HTML Table and server-side loaded elements?

Tags: mysql, ajax, html-table, datatables, lazy-loading

## Goal

My goal is to create a full-sized scrollable HTML table in which rows are lazy-loaded from a MySQL database.

---

## What I tried

I am using DataTables based on this example:

- [Scrollable extension - Server-side processing](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html)

  - on this page, the table data in this are generated by javascript

The content of my Data Table is loaded from a MySQL database:

- [Data sources - Server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

  - **lazy loading** is important in this case

---

## Result

Although the linked DetaTables guides working properly itself. When I combine the **Scrollable extension**, **Server-side processing** (lazy loading), and **100% height table**, the result is inappropriate:

- Only the first ajax element is loaded into the table, the other parts will remain unfilled. The ajax data is also not loaded as a result of scrolling.

  - Code snippet attached below

### Another attempt - Bootstrap

I tried to use the example about [Scrolling and Bootstrap tab](https://datatables.net/examples/api/tabs_and_scrolling.html)

- In this case, all of the rows are loaded by a single huge AJAX request and the client is overloaded (lazy loading not working).

---

## Code Snippet

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: "server_processing.php", //source: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html
    serverSide: true,
    ordering: true,
    searching: false,
    scrollX: true,
    scroller: {
        loadingIndicator: true
    }
  } );
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/2.0.3/css/scroller.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/2.0.3/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>



<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: "which rows are lazy-loaded from a MySQL"   how many rows are you talking about? and would it not be better to introduce some pagination? (see, i.e., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364349/pagination-using-mysql-limit-offset))

Comment: BTW, 100% height of what? The Eiffel tower?

Comment: The table can contain elements from 10 000 to 100 000. It is not exactly determined yet. I know pagination and it would work properly, but in this case especially important to use scrolling.

Comment: Updated the height

Comment: You're using a whole bunch of arguably outdated libraries to do this and piece everything together. Have you considered trying this with just plain javascript tools? You probably don't need these abstractions.

Comment: @Evert, What javascript tools do you recommend?

Comment: Sorry I meant, consider avoiding libraries and use plain CSS and Javascript.

Comment: @Evert I see, but how would the use of plain CSS and Javascript solve the problem? Could you show an example?

Comment: Sorry, I don't.. it's a fairly complex problem and will require a bunch of work to get everything together. I just think generally you'll have better luck long-term if you take the time to understand browser APIs instead of relying on jQuery snippets. If there's bugs, there's probably not going to be people around to fix them.