# How Do I Make A New Page Every So Many Inputs In PHP and SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make it so users can enter text files and a short message near it and it will be visible for everyone. I am using PHP and SQL (MariaDB/MySQL for the database) and I want it so every like ten for example inputs it will make a new page. So for example if there is ten files up on the page then if someone puts another one in it will automatically make a page two and have the oldest file submitted be there. How can I do this. I have seen other sites use a GET method and have it be something like ?page=2 . How can I do this myself?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is "Pagination".
[Pagination using MySQL LIMIT, OFFSET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364349/pagination-using-mysql-limit-offset)

Though that can look a bit scary at first. However, if you use a framework such as Laravel it can easily be done, see:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#introduction